# regex: how to find whether a string contains (a word OR another) AND any number?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am using Pandas to process a text variable, and I am not sure how to correctly write the following regex expression

- containing the word `ball` OR the word `hello` anywhere in the text
- contatining at least a number anywhere in the text

so that

- `ball red is good 02` is TRUE
- `ball ball` is FALSE
- `2003 was a pretty damn hello` is TRUE

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Wiktor I am sorry but I disagree. My regex is more complicated than the one on the link you provide, because there is an OR clause as well. Can you please re - open?

Comment: question edited

Comment: Yup: https://regex101.com/r/jGUzGK/1

Comment: @Wiktor: It has similarities but it is not a duplicate in my opinion.

Comment: @Jan, it is a code request, it is not a question. The regex you showed in the comment above is the same - two positive lookaheads.

Comment: are you serious?  how can this be not a question? also, I see your point of avoiding duplicates but with the OR condition I dont see how your link answers that

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Of course it is a code request. But I guess, if we start to be this picky, a great amount of questions are duplicates of others.

Comment: The point is that the question I closed with perfectly answers the question in its current form: it provides all necessary hints and technique to use. The rest is up to the user.